# Some transitive dependencies are downloaded only when built with maven 3

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

So, my project has a few dependencies that are deployed in a corporate nexus repository. When I build my project, one of the transitive dependencies (which is also one of our projects) is not downloaded correctly from the repository and the below error is seen instead.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: myTransitiveDependency

Reason: POM 'myTransitiveDependency' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  myTransitiveDependency

from the specified remote repositories:
  x (http://url/of/repo/x)

 for project myTransitiveDependency
```

My maven 2 executable:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 19:16:01+0000)
Java version: 1.6.0_35
Java home: /product/java/jdk1.6.0_35/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.18-371.el5" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

However if I use a maven 3 executable, say, `maven 3.2.3` (I tried a few other versions of maven 3 too), the transitive dependency is downloaded normally from the respective repo!

FWIW, the transitive dependency in question, `myTransitiveDependency`, is a `pom` type project and was built using maven 3. Is there any known bug with maven 2/3 that causes this problem? If so, is there any workaround?

Comment: what is the diff of `mvn dependency:tree` in both version of maven (actually both version of dependency plugin)

Comment: What is the exact error message cause the above is not the full error output?

Comment: @khmarbaise, that's actually the full error message. Anyway, I've added a couple of lines to the error message at the top indicating that the problem is not with the project being built, but rather with the transitive dependency in question. Not sure if it would be of any help though.

Comment: @JigarJoshi, are you wanting to see the dependency trees of the transitive dependency when run with m2 and m3? Or that of the project itself?

Comment: There is much more output before the end of the build which contains WARNINGS, exception etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise, there's really nothing. I can however see the actual full exception trace _after_ this error with `-X` enabled. Can't be that useful either, but let me know if you'd need them.